# I cant return a 2d array without using pointers ! im making a tic tac toe type game and this is my move up function

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

```
char[][]  moveup()
{
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
  {

   if(board[i][j]=='X' && board [i-1][j]=='!' ) {
    board [i][j]='!';
    board [i-1][j]='X';
    }
   }
   }
    return board;
  }
```

This is my code and *I want to pass this 2d array then in to a vector* so i want to return a 2d array board without using pointers

Comment: No, you cannot return array. If you want to do this, choose another language or wrap the array with structure.

Comment: Choosing *one of* either C or C++ should be good.

Comment: @MikeCAT IMO, it's perfectly valid to have both tags. Arrays work in almost exactly same way in both C and C++.

Comment: Let's not have a catfight please. The mice might get scared.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the arrays don't have the same status in C and C++. In C++ arrays are a low level construct nirmal people should not touch. Consequently, an answer which is good for C would be bad and misleading for C++. Formal correctness of an answer is required, but it's not the only thing required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a reference to the array:

```
char(&moveup())[3][3]
{
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {

            if (board[i][j]=='X' && board[i-1][j]=='!') {
                board[i][j]='!';
                board[i-1][j]='X';
            }
        }
    }
    return board;
}
```

Here is a full program passing the array by reference. Note how we can now use a range based for loop to iterate over the elements because the reference hasn't decayed to a pointer and the dimensions and type is preserved:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Board {

public:
    char(&moveup())[3][3]
    {
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {

                if (board[i][j]=='X' && board[i-1][j]=='!') {
                    board[i][j]='!';
                    board[i-1][j]='X';
                }
            }
        }
        return board;
    }

    char board[3][3];
};



int main()
{
    Board board{
        '.','!','x',
        'o','X','x',
        '.','o','x'
    };

    auto& sameboard = board.moveup();

    for (auto& row : sameboard) {
        for (auto& element : row) {
            std::cout << element;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the vector in and populate it in this function.